# Sending Ajax from java script to flask

Tags: python, json, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I've a big form of data of a table that i've turned into JSON object in Javascript but whenever i sent it to python its always imported as a large string object no matter what i do

jS data :

on top of the page

```
const ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.open('post' , "/addToTable");
ajaxRequest.onload = ()=>{
var parseRespons = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
```

at the bottom:

```
 const newJson = JSON.parse(jsonData);
 console.log(newJson[0]); // return a json object with the right formate
 const selectedTypeData = document.querySelector("#upType").value;

const fd = new FormData();

fd.append('selectedTypeData',selectedTypeData);
fd.append('newJson',newJson);


ajaxRequest.send(fd);
return false;
```

on python :

here are the methods i have tried

```
@app.route('/addToTable',methods=['POST'])
def addToTable():
print("active")
jD = requests.json("newJson") # print(jD[0]) ---> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

data = request.get_json() # print(jD) ---> None 
#jDD = request.form.get("jsonData") # print(jD[0]) ---> [
#jD_ = jsonify(jD)  # print(jD) ---> <Response 3219 bytes [200 OK]>
#jD = json.loads(response.text) #print(jD) --->  None
```

I don't know which method to import it to python as a JSON object.

Comment: Share the code of `upT`. Send `JSON.stringify(tData)` rather than parsing it.

Comment: done , i've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

jS = request.form.get("jsonData")
jD = json.loads(jS)
```

that fixed it for me .. toke over 24h of my life to figure that out